# requests routed through haproxy slower than direct invocations by large factors

Tags: haproxy

Requests routed through haproxy (v 1.5-dev19) consistently run **5-6 times slower** than identical requests executed against the relevant haproxy backend directly, from the same Ubuntu server. wget Unix utility used in both invocations. Not sure why this is happening or what parameters to tune to eliminate this unacceptable penalty. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no reason for this to be the expected behavior, but version 1.5-dev19 seems like an unacceptably old version of HAProxy.

Comment: direct: time wget -O file --save-headers --header="Host: replicon.sitesuite.netstellar.com" http://10.0.2.38:999/ui/bundles/app
real 0m0.154s
user 0m0.023s
sys 0m0.037s

via haproxy: time wget -O file --save-headers --header="Host: replicon.sitesuite.netstellar.com" http://127.0.0.1:80/ui/bundles/app
real 0m2.876s
user 0m0.000s
sys 0m0.037s

I'm stumped...Slower by a factor of 20...
Is there a setting I could use to tune this up?

Comment: It should not be a matter of "tuning."  HAProxy is normally quite blazingly fast by default.  What is the log message HAProxy wrote for this request?

Comment: Jun 17 02:15:07 localhost ha-main[8768]: 127.0.0.1:- [17/Jun/2018:02:15:03.238] http sitekick-replicon/sites-sitekick-replicon 0/0/1/1/4297 200 1245726 - - ---- 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 replicon.sitesuite.netstellar.com "GET /ui/bundles/app" HTTP/1.1"

There is something else I've noticed - haproxy performs pretty darn well if you leave it alone for an extended period of time (1 hour or so). Then after a few identical requests it decides to get in a rut again